# Angular router sending GET request instead of loading component

Tags: .net, angular

When I navigate to the /exercises page, I get a blank page that displays the result of the GetAllExercises method instead of the ExerciseListComponent. However, if I change the path to 'exercise' in my RouterModule, it no longer matches with the controller and loads the ExerciseListComponent correctly. Why is it directly accessing the controller instead of loading the component?

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'exercises', component: ExerciseListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'workout-plans', component: WorkoutPlanListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'workout-sessions', component: WorkoutSessionListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
])
```

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("exercises")]
public JsonResult GetAllExercises()
{
    var context = new WorkoutTrackerContext();
    var exercises = context.Exercises.ToList();
    return Json(exercises);
}
```

Comment: This is incoherent. Please explain the relationship between the client and server code, what you're trying to accomplish, and why you expect it to work

Comment: The symptoms sound really weird. I suggest first logging all the router events. What is happening there?

Comment: My issue is that there should not be a relationship between the client and server code in this instance. When I navigate to '/exercises', I expect the client to load the ExerciseListComponent and nothing else. However, it is sending a GET request to /exercises instead.

Comment: Have you tried changing the route on the server side to be something like `api/exercises` rather than `exercises`. Right now the server side and client side route names match. Make them different.

Comment: @mbojko The exercises route is the only one that doesn't have any output when logging.  My guess is that its not matching for some reason, but I have no idea why.

Comment: @R.Richards Yes, making them different works. My only concern with that is that I'm using MVC, not Web API, so I don't know if including "api" in my server side routes would be a good practice. I'm also curious as to why the RouterModule would be prioritizing server side routes over client side routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it. It has nothing to do with the `RouterModule`. Or even Angular at all. The only actors of the drama are the browser and the backend.

I guess your backend redirects all *unknown* routes to the `index.html` which bootstraps the Angular app - but `/exercises` is a *known* route. Hence the JSON, instead of the component - actually, the JSON instead of the Angular app and its interpretation of the route.

One solution would be to use something more specific than `'/'` as the base href (dunno, `/app` for Angular, `/service` for the API?).